# "Squeeze out" multiple zeros in a vector and keep indices

Tags: c++, arrays

I have a `vector` `A` with `N` numbers in it. I want to replace every occurrence of multiple contiguous zeros with just one zero and keep track of the indices of elements that are not removed.

That means, in the end I would get a `vector` `B` of some `length <= N` that has only one zero where `A` had one or more contiguous zeros and all other elements of `A` as they were. In a third `vector` `Index`, I would get the numbers `0` to `N-1`, if `A` has no multiple zeros in a row or left out indices where multiple zeros occurred.

So for example:

Input:

> A = {1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1}

Output

> B = {1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 1}
>
> Index = {0, 1, 2, 5, 6, 7}

How could I do that?

Comment: Can you show your attempt as code? This shouldn't be that hard.

Comment: Is it acceptable if these are `std::vector` and not `std::array`? Doing this with `std::array` is possible but extremely difficult.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat C++17. Is there actually a command for that in C++20 or why are you asking?

Comment: I didn't ask. Somebody else did, but they deleted their comment. I don't know a C++20 oneliner for this.

Comment: @MooingDuck It is not only acceptable, these are already std::vector ;-)

Comment: @PaulAner *but I can't seem to find a solution...* -- This should be just a `for` loop over `A`, and building up `B` and `Index` with some `if/else` logic.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I know, that was my approach, too. Sounds really simple, but I allways get stuck. Maybe today isn't a brain-day for me and I should try again tomorrow. But maybe someone here can code that in 2 minutes... ;-)

Comment: Can you show the code you ended up with, and tell us what it does wrong?

Comment: @PaulAner Oh well, I was going to post some code but the question was closed. It really is one for loop, containing one if statement (that checks if the current element in A is a repeated zero). Maybe you'll figure it out tomorrow.

Comment: Here's how to figure this out, this always works! Take out a blank sheet of paper. Write down a step-by-step process of doing this, as short, brief sentences in plain words. [Have your rubber duck review your plan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging). Generally, we don't write code for other people, on Stackoverflow. We always refer such questions to their rubber duck. After your rubber duck approves your proposed plan of action, simply take what you've written down and translate it directly into C++, and you're done! Have you discussed this with your rubber duck, yet?

Comment: This is a clearly defined, narrowly scoped, programming question. Whether the OP has attempted to solve it themself is completely irrelevant to the closure of a question. Voting to reopen.

Answer (score 1):

I finally got this to work and maybe someone stumbles upon this post and finds this helpfull:

```
bool last_was_zero = false;
for (int y = 0; y < N; y++)
{
    if (last_was_zero)
    {
        if (A[y] > 0)
        {
            B.push_back(A[y]);
            C.push_back(y);
            last_was_zero = false;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        B.push_back(A[y]);
        C.push_back(y);
        if (A[y] == 0)
        {
            last_was_zero = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would ditch the `last_was_zero` variable. A simple test `if (y > 0 && A[y - 1] == 0 && A[y] == 0)` tells all you need to know. If this is true do not add `A[y]` to `B`, otherwise do. This greatly simplifies the code, only one if statement, only one place where `B` and `C` get updated.